# Kendo UI Drop Down loading data from model

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have a standard Order form with a product  selection. I am creating a dropdown list as per below where ProductName and ID are properties of the Product reference data model. ProductID is a property of the Order model. 
The dropdown is loaded and works correctly when submitting the form.

My problem is when the user opens this form again to view his order. I load the Order model from the database and I can see that the ProductID is correctly loaded back. However, the dropdown selection remains blank. Is this standard behaviour? Perhaps I need to carry out some additional tasks. Doesn't kendo ui automatically translate the Product ID to show the Product Name in the dropdown?

```
@model int
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("ProductID") 
    .OptionLabel(" ")
    .DataTextField("ProductName")
    .DataValueField("ID")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("RefDataClientSelection_Read", "RefDataClient").Type(HttpVerbs.Post); //Set the Action and Controller name
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true); //If true the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
    })

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DropDownListFor()` as below:

```
@model int
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m) // or m => m.ProductId if you have a more complex model
    .OptionLabel(" ")
    .DataTextField("ProductName")
    .DataValueField("ID")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("RefDataClientSelection_Read", "RefDataClient").Type(HttpVerbs.Post); //Set the Action and Controller name
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true); //If true the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
    })

)
```